# pull up to reload in collectionview using uiview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

i have a collection view which is used to show comment and i am using a uiview at bottom of the view controller with a height of 0.
when user reach the bottom of content in collection view,as he pull up past content i check in scrollviewdidscroll

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if self.comment.count >= 5 {
            let  offseety = scrollView.contentOffset.y
            let contenthight = scrollView.contentSize.height
            if offseety > contenthight - scrollView.frame.size.height + 5 && offseety > 50{
                if self.viewheight.constant < 50 {
                    self.viewheight.constant =  scrollView.frame.size.height - contenthight + offseety
                    if offseety > contenthight - scrollView.frame.size.height + 50{

                        self.anddiii.isHidden = false
                        self.anddiii.startAnimating()
                        self.anothershit.isHidden = false
                        self.anothershit.text =  "Loading more"
                    }
                }}else{

            }
        }
    }
```

but problem after scrolling end the collection view scrolls back,is there a way to put an ofset bellow last collection cell to show uiview in

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code:

`self.collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,55,0)`